# Download Files from File Table SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, download, filetable

I am using a `FileTable` in SQL Server 2012 and I want my users to download files from the `FileTable`. What path should I use?

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string filename)
{
    //string filename = Request.QueryString["MOVIE_FILE"];
    string path = "\\Maaz-laptop\\mssqlservermaaz\\FileDBFileStreamDirectory\\FileDirectory";
    Response.ContentType = "application/force-download;";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(path) + filename);
    Response.End();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get access to the path by following query which can be a SQL function:

```
USE database_name;
DECLARE @root nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @fullpath nvarchar(1000);

SELECT @root = FileTableRootPath();
SELECT @fullpath = @root + file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath()
    FROM filetable_name
    WHERE name = N'document_name';

PRINT @fullpath;
GO
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/gg492087(v=sql.110).aspx)'s the source from MSDN, Hope it'll help somebody.

Keep in mind that it's an address to windows share folder which can't make a proper address for download, you need to change it to a valid address starting with your domain name or an address that your IIS recognizes, in the given link, 2 more SQL functions has been offered, try them too, I'm still looking for a proper address for making a download link.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following path for example

```
\\SERVERNAME\FILESTREAM_WINDOWS_SHARE_NAME\FILESTREAM_TABLE_NAME\FILETABLE_DIRECTORY\
```

Please follow this link for information [FileTable Example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2667/filetable-feature-in-sql-server-2012/)

Comment: I just voted you up since I saw somebody voted you down by no reason, your answer might not be the exact answer but you did your best, I hate this manner that people vote down without any comment for that, I have had such experiences!